# Business Logic when Saving in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

If I want to perform some action when an entity is saved, I can do something as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx).

However, suppose I retrieve an object from the database. This object has a list of items within it. If I instantiate a new item and add it to this list and then save all changes, the item in the list is not part of the "GetObjectStateEntries".

Comment: your question makes no sense, please clarify what you trying to do with some example code. also are you by any chance using POCO's or self-tracking entities? or are you using "off the shelf" Entity Framework (code generation)

Comment: @RPM1984 Sorry if my question confuses you. There is a link in my question to a relevant MSDN article. If you understand that article you might understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for my situation, I believe, has been resolved. There appears to be a bug, in my opinion, in the ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions) method. Even though this method will call DetectChanges (depending on the saveOptions), the OnSavingChanges method is called FIRST. This, I think, is a problem.

The solution to this is to call ObjectContext.DetectChanges() prior to calling SaveChanges().